# Images upload with PHP: how to optimize space, bandwidth and performance

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm planning to develop an area where the users can upload pictures. I know how to upload a picture on the server using PHP but the problem is what is the best practice to develop a performing system.

The idea is to display in different pages thumbs and I would like to know if it's a better idea to save two different images (thumb + original) on the server or if it's better to save just the original and create all the thumbs on the fly. Thumb + original means more space on the server, whereas the option "thumbs on the fly" means most likely a server overload.

I found couple of good scripts to resize and cropping on the fly but not sure if it's a good idea to use especially if the web site has few thousands visitor per day (or may be more in the future just to be optimistic/pessimistic).

Comment: Definitely save the thumbs. What sounds more reasonable, storing a ~30-100kB thumbnail (and maybe purge them periodically) or waste ~10% CPU on EVERY hit?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely generate and save the thumbnails on disk.  Storage is cheap.

Comment: Just for curiosity. Huge websites like Facebook or Flickr how do they manage this kind of situations?

Comment: They have insanely large data stores, caching layers, and content distribution networks.  They have problems of scale unlike anything you would probably expect to encounter, so trying to emulate their solution is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate some thumbnails and save them on disk but in the long term that's problematic due to different devices needing different sizes, different formats, etc.

If you are already saving the uploaded images on S3, Azure Storage, or Google Cloud I recommend to use some on the fly image processing service like [imglab](https://imglab.io) or [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com).

With these services you can generate many different types of cropping, and serving them in different (modern) formats like WebP or AVIF so you don't need to generate them before hand. SEO will be improved wit this option too.

Additionaly images will be behind a global CDN so users will get the images in a fast way independent or their location.